# Prevent Django from joining superclass' table

Tags: django, optimization, inheritance, model, django-queryset

Having a non-abstract parent class:

```
class Animal(models.Model)
```

and two subclasses:

```
class Cow(Animal)
class Dog(Animal)
```

and calling

```
Dog.objects.order_by('name')
```

queries the database and returns joined records:

```
SELECT ... FROM dog 
INNER JOIN animal ON (dog.animal_ptr_id = animal.id) 
ORDER BY dog.name ASC
```

However in my case "dog" is not a table, but a complicated view defined in the database. The view already contains all needed fields from "animal" including the animal id accessible by animal_ptr__id.

How can I prevent django from making the INNER JOIN which drastically slows down the query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you think `dog` is not a table in this case, since you are not using abstract base class. It is therefore [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) and each subclass *does* have a table.

To the best of my knowledge the best way to avoid `INNER JOIN` for multi-table inheritance is to use [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) by setting `abstract = True` in `class Meta`. It seems like this what you should be doing, but..

It is possible, however, to use [raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) if you insist on using multi-table inheritance. Something like this *might* work:

```
Dog.objects.raw('SELECT ... FROM myapp_dog ORDER BY dog.name ASC')
```

Though `dog` table alone will not contain the properties it inherited from the base class `Animal`. To get those inherited properties, I think a `JOIN` is unavoidable unless I missed something obvious..

Comment: I would make Animal an abstract base class. However the Animal is referenced by a `Value` model (attribute_id, attribute_value, animal_id) and I access them with `.attribute_set`. Thus I think I need to have the non-abstract Animal for proper foreign key lookup.

Comment: The `dog` view is defined directly in the database, it is also made that it contains all the properties of Animal.

Comment: @tomasz If 'dog' is defined to include all Animal property in your db, then you can just use the raw query like I mentioned.

Comment: This looks promising, but how can I make the raw query act as a queryset in the model manager? I think I need to subclass `db.models.sql.query.Query` and override join_map or some other fields, and then use it in my custom manager like this:
`def get_query_set(self):
      return QuerySet(model=Dog, query=MyNoJoinQuery(model=Dog))`

Comment: When I use `.raw()` method as the QuerySet I get `'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'filter'`. I can't even use `extra()` with `RawQuerySet`s.

Answer (score 0):

> However in my case "dog" is not a table, but a complicated view
>   defined in the database.

You need to set [`managed = False`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed) for `Dog`; otherwise you aren't using your view but an intermediary table called `app_dog` (where `app` is your app name).

This prevents django from creating a table but to use one internally defined (in your case, the view). Make sure you also specify a [key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), and specify the [table name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table).

Comment: I had already set the table name, and indeed I really should have set `managed = False`. But these don't eliminate the `inner join` from the query.

Comment: Did you do a migration or recreate the database after you did this?

Comment: I don't have rights to issue DDL queries. I am writing an application for an existing database.